# The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found while running tests

Tags: .net

I'm feeling a bit confused. Everything was (probably) running OK until I decided to move from VS2019 to VS2022 Preview.

I have a fairly usual WPF .NET 5 project ([here](https://github.com/bruno-brant/dotnet-take-a-break)) and I'm trying to run tests locally from the CLI (I'm debugging the error that is being seem on GitHub - it doesn't happen from within VS2022):

`dotnet tests`

I get the following error:

> Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any
> compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App',
> version '5.0.0' was not found.
>
> - The following frameworks were found:
>   6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12 at [C:\Aplic\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\dotnet\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] You
>   can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or
>   SDK. The specified framework can be found at:
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
>   . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

It seems straight-forward as far as error messages go. Only:

```
❯ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0-preview.7.21378.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

So something is really wrong. The CLI can find the required framework (well, at least, a close *minor* version) but when running it blows up. What is wrong?

Comment: Picking a custom install location for a preview edition is never a good idea, the installer is always the last thing they get right.  Well, the uninstaller is, installer next.

Comment: @HansPassant could be the case... but I thought that the dotnet cli was independent from VS...after all, all frameworks are installed in the same place which I guess is the default.

Comment: Similar issue on Linux, where I only installed in standard paths via dotnet. I have Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 but they cannot find Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0. OK, technically it's not the same patch, but surely it should be compatible?